# SSR rendering Vue with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I have developed a Vue app and a Laravel app and connected them with Vuex,VueRouter and the API endpoints, now I want to implement SSR. So far I have found 2 methods for implementing SSR:

- use PhpV8js and Render Vue SSR in Laravel blade
- use 2 separate processes: Laravel (php-fpm) and VueSSR (node)

  1. accept the request in Laravel and render session dependent data like user info, queries on repositories in json
  2. pass session json to node proccess (with socket or http)
  3. node process renders Vue app with session data and passes it back to laravel
  4. laravel renders the SSR blade with rendered Vue app

my concerns for first the method is: I don't like using PhpV8js in production environment with lots of traffic and a Vue component heavy app!

for second one: I don't know if passing html pages back and forth between socket apps is a good idea.

for a production environment which of these do you prefer? which will be the most performant? and are there other ways to accomplish Vue+Laravel SSR?

Comment: I looked into it a 2 years ago but my general thought was that it was too difficult to do/maintain in php. V8js would indeed be a solution but you had to trick it into being a Node.js environment by setting all kinds of properties. The better documented way is to use Node.js and use the official SSR modules from Vue, but as you might expect its not trivial at all to get this to work with Laravel blade files. Thats my 2 cents :)

Comment: Another solution is to create a js script that generates the markup and outputs it in the standard output and then invoke it using a `shell_exec` type of solution and pass the result into a variable in the view to fill in the Vue bits. I think this is the most straight forward way without dragging in too many other dependencies

Comment: @apokryfos that is indeed another solution, but with my setup in a docker swarm it evolved into running 2 separate containers and doing a ``socket`` connection instead of running shell_exec. And in more depth I think using ``shell_exec`` would result in node engine creating and destroying itself on each request, but using a native node process and passing the data between it and laravel makes better use of memory and cpu needs to setup environment only once, but needs SSR friendly code